# accept parameters from sql table in adf pipeline

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-sql-server

I have a request to select the values from a sql table and pass it to adf pipeline
example:

> sql table-->abc with columns(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)

I need to pass the col1 to col5 values as input to a pipeline abc.

how can we do that please suggest or if it is feasible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below flow to achieve the same:

1. Lookup activity: this would include your select query
2. After lookup activity >>> Execute pipeline activity wherein you would pass the lookup activity output values as input to the pipeline
   @activity('LookupActivityNm').output.value[0].col1
   @activity('LookupActivityNm').output.value[0].col2